# How to use random.seed with random.randn?

Tags: python, numpy, random-seed

I can seed an intenteger random number generator by doing:

```
import random    
random.seed(9002)   
random.randint(1, 10)
```

and the same integer number is generated every time.

On the other hand, when I try to do the same to generate real numbers, the seed is not fixing the generated number to the same value every time.

```
import random   
random.seed(9001)
np.random.randn(1)
```

How can I seed np.random.randn ?

Comment: Is this python? I don't think these tags are appropriate. Also, np is possibly numpy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seed numpy's random number generator.

```
np.random.seed(0)
np.random.randn(1)
```

That should always produce the same array.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import randn
```

You need to import `numpy` first, then `randn`

To call seed -

```py
np.random.seed(101) # This can be any number.
```

This allows you to create an array from random numbers with the same number each time. This allows you to test outputs or check your work against a tutorials output.